# How do I apply to use the API in my iPhone app?

Tags: facebook, api

I have all the coding complete but need a token (or certificate) from Facebook in order to launch my app. Where do I get this?

Comment: check http://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/access-tokens-and-types/

Answer (score 0):

Facebook's Developer [site](https://developers.facebook.com/) would be absolutely the place to start

They have alot of great tutorials there too.

And here is the [link](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) to create a new Facebook app and with it you will get an App Secret and ID. With those you can use the Facebook API, ofcourse you need access tokens from the users. The website has good documentation and examples on how to do this

Answer (score 0):

developers.facebook.com

Go to your app and you should have all there. How have you been testing without this before ?

Are you sure you are not referring to the IOS certificate to launch the app on the appstore ?

Could you specify what you are looking for?